# UICollectionView and images

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`, and it works great, but I have a doubt.
In my view I have a `UICollectionViewCell` and inside that I have a UIImage.
The cell is linked to a blank view controller, and inside that I have a `UIScrollView` (for managing the zoom) and a `UIImage` (the full-size image).

I wondered if there was some delegate or something that could handle the image opening process automatically (with zoom, etc.).

Now I'm handling the zoom effect with `UIScrollViewDelegate` delegate and method `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`... but the result is very poor, definitely not fluid!

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049056/uicollectionview-and-images.

Comment: wrong link...? this is linking this question

Comment: Oops, sorry: here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053486/uiscrollview-uiimage-and-zoom-not-fluid

Comment: I want to do the same thing with you: the UICollectionView contains a UIScrollView, the UIScrollView contains a UIImageView. In the subclass of UICollectionView, I add viewForZoomingInScrollView(...), but it's not called. I don't know why. Could you give me some hint?

Comment: I really can't help you... I'm definitely not a pro with Objective C, sorry! Try to open a new question, maybe you could refer to this question in order to give some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in view for doing what you want, no. You're doing the right thing with a `UIImageView` inside `UIScrollView`. If it's not very fluid, then it's likely because your image is huge. The way to get around that is to load different images for different zoom levels. So as you zoom in, listen to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method called `scrollViewDidZoom:` and change the image to better resolution as you zoom in. Or, take a look at `CATiledLayer`.

Note that this has nothing to do with your `UICollectionView`.

Comment: The image isn't that huge... is only 640x480!

Comment: Oh ok. Well I think maybe you should open a new question specific to why your image in scroll view is not fluid. Show your code and if possible, image sample.