# UIScrollView + UIImage and zoom: not fluid

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimage, ios6

I have view controller, and inside that I have a `UIScrollView`, for managing the zoom, and a `UIImage`.
Now I'm handling the zoom effect with `UIScrollViewDelegate` delegate and method `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`... but the result is very poor, definitely not fluid!

This is my code:

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ImageViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ImageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;

    // some code
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}
// last update
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([self.scrollView zoomScale] < 1.0) {
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:1.0];
    }
}

// some other methods...

@end
```

This is the storyboard view:

[image]
[image]

I'm not using a Pinch Gesture Recognizer.
All images are quite small like 640x480.

Thanks

*P.S. this is a continue of [UICollectionView and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049056/uicollectionview-and-images).*

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here. When you say it's not fluid, do you mean it's jerky when zooming / panning / both?

Comment: Yes, a lot! I mean, when I zoom in Pictures or even in other App, like Twitter or IMDB, the zoom i very fluid!

Comment: Well from the code and screenshot you posted, I can't see anything wrong. So the problem must lie elsewhere. Are you doing some intensive work in `scrollViewDidZoom:` maybe?

Comment: I posted a video to show you the problem: http://youtu.be/XbW-7umSbsQ ...maybe is everything alright and it's only about iOS Simulator!

Comment: Can you show some more code of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods you implement please?

Comment: I've just edited my post adding `scrollViewDidZoom:` method.

Comment: Is that the only one you implement?

Comment: Does this help you - http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content - it's a tutorial I wrote. The first part is exactly what you need to implement.

Comment: That tutorial looks awesome! that's exactly what I want. As soon as I have some time off, I'll take a look. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I've added an answer with that then. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout out this [tutorial I wrote](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content). The first part is exactly what you need to implement.

Comment: @mattjgalloway Any chance the tutorial gets updated to work with iOS 6 autolayout feature?. Embedding a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView and get it to scroll and zoom is not that straightforward with autolayout..

Comment: @mattjgalloway: awesome tutorial about scroll + image .

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in other posts:

[Zooming image views with autolayout:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026807/uiscrollview-zooming-with-auto-layout/16159139#16159139)

[Centering logic for autolayout or springs and struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197572/using-uiscrollview-when-zooming-out-how-can-i-keep-the-content-view-at-the-cen/16310804#16310804)