# UIScrollView can't zoom in iOS7 with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

i have created an UIScrollView with this hierarchy (my sample is AutoLayout)

```
UIViewController
  UIView
     UIScollView
       ContainerView
          UIImageView
```

[image]

everything work fine in iOS 8 - 9 expect **iOS 7**

i can zoom my ImageView in iOS 7

i have implemented  :

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
 {
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
CGSize scrollableSize =  CGSizeMake(self.imageView.frame.size.width,self.imageView.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0  ;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4;

  }



-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 return self.containerView;
}
```

i have checked this links :
[UIScrollView zooming with Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026807/uiscrollview-zooming-with-auto-layout)
[Scroll View not functioning IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502860/scroll-view-not-functioning-ios-7)

**Problem**

**zoom not work in iOS 7 , ( i need to use Auto Layout ) and my UIImageview should have a AspectFit Ratio**

i uploaded my sample on github :

[sampleProject](https://github.com/mfarhand/sampleScrollView)

Comment: Using auto-layouts you don't need to set the content view programatically I think